# Toolbar blinks when transitioning from fragment to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, toolbar, shared-element-transition

I have a toolbar in my parent Activity. There are two children-fragments. When I press the FAB button to transition between fragments, the toolbar blinks. What can I do to fix it? Thank you!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOtGu.gif)

**Main Activity**

*XML:*

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarTheme"/>
```

*Kotlin:*

```
navController = findNavController(R.id.myNavHostFragment)
    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
```

**Fragment A**

*XML:*

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:transitionName="shared_element_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        />
```

*Kotlin:*

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
     postponeEnterTransition()
    binding = FragmentListBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    binding.root.doOnPreDraw {
        startPostponedEnterTransition()
    }
    return binding.root
```

**Fragment B**

*XML:*

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:transitionName="shared_element_container">
```

*Kotlin:*

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform()
    sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform()
}
```

**Solved:** What worked for me is that I deleted my toolbar from main activity and changed the app theme from '(name of theme)'.NoActionBar  to  '(name of theme)'.DarkActionBar. So I put toolbar in the theme and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is that I deleted my toolbar from main activity and changed the app theme from '(name of theme)'.NoActionBar to '(name of theme)'.DarkActionBar. So I put toolbar in the theme and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

When you animate using SharedElement transition, you need to exclude the views that you don't to animate.

Something like this:

```
val animation = MaterialContainerTransform() // Initialize the default animation
animation.excludeTarget(R.id.toolbar, true) // Exclude your toolbar from said animation
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it made no difference for me

Answer (score 0):

MaterialContainerTransform has a method called setDrawingViewId(@IdRes int drawingViewId)

So you want to call it as such on your MaterialContainerTransform object.

`materialContainerTransform.setDrawingViewId(R.id.view_id_here)`

Documentation for this method: "Set the id of the View whose overlay this transition will be added to. This can be used to limit the bounds of the animation (including the background scrim) to the bounds of the provided drawing view, and also have the animation drawn at the relative z-order of the drawing view. By default, the drawingViewId will be android.R.id.content. Additionally, if drawingViewId is the same as the end View's id, MaterialContainerTransform will add the transition's drawable to the drawingViewId's parent instead. If the drawing view cannot be found during the initialization of the MaterialContainerTransform, then an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown."

I was looking for this solution myself. @Barry Irvine's answer was useful, because the documentation for the setScrimColor() method references the drawingViewId, which is what the scrim color fills. You want to apply this to a view that does not include the toolbar, and your issue will go away without getting rid of the Scrim Color concept, which obviously has a purpose, else they would not have included it.

I posted this same answer to another related post earlier today.